# Convert format HDF to 2D NetCDF

Tags: qgis, netcdf, hdf

I need to convert an HDF to NetCDF. In the version 2.18 I used to go to Raster-Conversion-and convert, and changing in the console to change 'GMT' by 'netcdf', which allowed me to obtain a 2D .nc. However, in the last versions of QGIS is not possible, and thus, the final NetCDF is a file with 1D and not 2D. And I need a file with longitude and latitude.

```
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:4326 -of GMT
```

Comment: May not be a wise idea, but how about using `Batch Processing` mode? There you'll find **Converted** parameter (the fifth from the left) which allows you to select `nc` option.